# How do I tell ActiveRecord not to log any control chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way to tell active record not to log the ansi color codes when its logging stuff?

Eg. I do not want this in my logs.

```
[4;36;1mSQL (0.1ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `users` WHERE (`user`.id = 133) [0m
```

Instead I want this:

```
SQL (0.1ms) SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `users` WHERE (`user`.id = 133)
```

I am not looking for a solution that involves cleaning up the mess after the fact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer for Rails 3:

```
config.colorize_logging = false
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html

> ActiveRecord::Base.colorize_logging and
>   config.active_record.colorize_logging  are deprecated in favor of 
>   Rails::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging or config.colorize_logging

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your appropriate environment file (in my case development.rb)

```
config.active_record.colorize_logging = false
```

Comment: this answer is valid for rails < 3

Answer (score 5):

I use this method in my jRuby scripts.
The part that disables the coloring is

```
ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging = false
```

get_jar_path is another method that returns the correct path in case the script is in a JAR

```
def activate_logger scriptname
  # delete logs after a month
  $log = Logger.new( "#{get_jar_path}/logs/#{scriptname}_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.txt", 'monthly' )
  # $log = Logger.new($stdout) 
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = $log
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger.const_get($debuglevel)
  ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging = false
  $errors, $verwerkt = 0, 0
  $log.info "start #{__FILE__}"
end
```