# How can I colorize logger output in a rails 3 console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, ruby-on-rails-3, irb

How can I colorize and possibly bold the output from Rails.logger in my rails3 application?

Answer (score 7):

Be kind to other programmers, don't embed the escape sequences directly in your strings. Maybe use a library like [Rainbow](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rainbow/) or [Term-ANSIColor](http://flori.github.com/term-ansicolor/)? Eg Term-ANSIColor:

```
require 'term/ansicolor'
include Term::ANSIColor

Rails.logger.add 1, "#{red(ATCHUNG!)}: pay attention to me!"
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do I tell ActiveRecord not to log any control chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286001/how-do-i-tell-activerecord-not-to-log-any-control-chars)

just do the opposite, for active record

also see  this link

http://joefiorini.com/post/64995867/coloring-in-the-rails-log-and-console